# How to view Gmail sender via app script? in a delegated account

Tags: google-apps

How can I get the "Sent by" value from emails sent from this Gmail account in Google Apps Script?
I have access to this mailbox and there is a sender display in the GUI. You can look at the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsW8q.png)

When I use the GmailApp get From() function it returns the alias but not the mail sender.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.